# Buddypress plugin Group Hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy, buddypress

Buddypress has a group functionality in which I combined with the plugin BP Group Hierarchy so that I can create an hierarchy of groups based on user role.

However, the plugin used an method as taught by Buddpress in group-extension-api> link.

The group steps are registered using the function bp_register_group_extension and add_action are called. I tried to remove the action by with no success. Because I not really understand how the array works i.e. array( &$extension, \'_register\' ), so I go search out and found this [post](http://funcdoc.wordpress.com/2008/01/13/writing-plugins-what-is-the-class-callback-format/).

There's a line stating that

> The new format for the above object referenced method callbacks are always: class name, followed immediately by the method name, followed by the amount of previously added (classname+methodname). For classes, this allows you to add as many object referenced classes and add methods which don’t override each other.

However I can't seems to be able to remove the action.

I tried to remove the action by putting following lines of code in function.php

> function remove_bp_hierarchy(){
>
> > if (has_action('bp_actions')) {
> >
> > > echo $extension = new BP_Groups_Hierarchy_Extension;
> > >
> > > remove_action('bp_actions', array( &$extension, '_register' ), 999);
> >
> > } else {
> >
> > }
> >
> > add_action('bp_init','remove_bp_hierarchy', 999);

Is it something wrong with my remove_action or I use wrong method? Thanks and regards.

## Update

Found a [page](http://www.wprecipes.com/list-all-hooked-wordpress-functions) in which let we see a list of hooks and also hooked function in the page. I see that there's a function with the name _register which is the function I'm looking for. However, class address always change. I was thinking using the function found to do a preg_match on it and remove it when it found. this is super heavy. So is there other way of removing it? Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Now temporalily solve it by using

global $wp_filter;
$the_key = key($wp_filter['bp_actions'][8]);
unset($wp_filter['bp_actions'][8] );

which like a hardcore wordpress remove_action

Answer (score 3):

CodingBabyDotCom -

Long story short: you will have to traverse the `$wp_filter` array to remove the action.

You need a reference to the SAME instance that was used to create the action in order to remove it with the `remove_action` function. So the function you posted doesn't work because it is using a new instance.

Unfortunately `bp_register_group_extension()` creates only a temporary instance, so it can't be referenced by later functions.

The code in your comment will remove ALL actions at level 8, which means all group extensions. To remove only the one you want, iterate over each filter and check its type with:

`is_a( $wp_filter['bp_actions'][8][$key], 'BP_Groups_Hierarchy_Extension' )`